# How to add user funds using Stripe?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

It's my first time using Stripe, and I read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/billing#stripe-configuration) documentation about it.

I was able to find information about subscriptions and plans, but I need something else, something like "user credits". Each user will be able to "add funds" to their account, and buy products on my website using this money.

In addition, I need to be able to automatically add funds for the user once it gets empty ( with their permissions, of course ).

Can it be done using Stripe? Does the API support such thing?

Comment: Stripe isn't a bank, so other than making pro-rata credits to a subscription, I don't think it has a *credit* concept. It sounds more likely that you're going to need to charge the user's card, and to track and hold the monies within your own business. The legal and tax implications of doing this would be something to consider and certainly beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: @fubar what about using [Simple Charges](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/billing#single-charges)? Maybe I can charge the user's account and save the added funds to the users table

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. You will need to charge them and track how much money they have remaining.